# How do you sum two values containing the dollar sign "$"? I have been trying to figure out the methods and properties, still no clue

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, input

```
//for example 
allInputs[22].value //equals $45 and
allInputs[4].value  // equals $70

allInputs[22].value + allInputs[4].value = "$45$70"
```

It equals "$45$70". But I only want to sum up the value. how do I sum up both values to get the final value ignoring the dollar sign?

Comment: Replace $ with empty string, then parse the strings to int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
"$" + (parseInt(allInputs[22].value.substring(1)) + parseInt(allInputs[22].value.substring(1)))
```

The `substring` method, will get rid of the **$** sign, and `parseInt` will convert it to a number. You need that, because if you do not use that it will concatenate the values as strings. Note that i put another set of brackets to sum the numbers. That is because, when the interpreter sees the **"$"** it thinks it should concatenate strings. But we want to sum the numbers and then concatenate the sum with the **"$"** string.

Comment: If you're going to use `parseInt` make sure to include the radix value: `parseInt(str, 10)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and check for a non-number sign at the beginning of a value:

```js
var allInputs = ["$45","$70"];
var sum = allInputs.reduce(function(pre, curr){
  if(isNaN(curr[0]))return pre+(+curr.slice(1));
  return pre+curr;
},0);

console.log('$'+sum);
```

Comment: This really only works if the inputs are consecutive. In the example the inputs are the 22nd and the 4th.

Answer (score 2):

This is a general function expression that accepts the string value from a form input and returns a number.

```
const getNumber = (val) => Number(val.match(/[\d\.]+/));
```

You can use it like this:

```
const sum = getNumber(allInputs[22].value) + getNumber(allInputs[4].value);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rLhqt3g6/3/)**

Note: ideally you should store the currency value ($, £, € etc) separately from the values so this doesn't become an issue.

Comment: This worked too. But I'm quite new to the const. LOL

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need `parseFloat()`. Accordingly the following would be my helper function.

```js
function addDollars(s1,s2){
  var n1 = parseFloat(s1.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")),
      n2 = parseFloat(s2.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""));
  return "$"+ (n1+n2).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(addDollars("$123.42","$12.88"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
parseFloat(allInputs[22].value.slice(1)) + parseFloat(allInputs[4].value.slice(1))
```

Remember that string are arrays.
if you want to end up with the "$" sign then just concatenate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the "$" and convert the `strings` into `numbers` to sum them up.

### Code

You can remove the "$" with [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) like `allInputs[22].value.replace('$', '')` this will return `"42"` as a string.
Now we need to convert this string into a number. There are many [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript) to do  this. I use [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) in the following solution.

### Solution

```js
var someMoney = '$50'
var moreMoney = '$60'

var toMuchMoney = "$" + Number(someMoney.replace('$', '')) + Number(moreMoney.replace('$', ''))

console.log(toMuchMoney)
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, You should know about the difference between `concatenation` and `addtion` in javascript.

If you add two strings, You get concatenation of both strings as answer

`"$45" + "$70" = "$45$70"`

If you add two integers, you get addition.

`45 + 70 = 115`

So, to solve your problem, You need to first extract numbers from your variables and then do addition on them. 
To extract numbers you can use any method but I am using `split`.
To convert string into integer you can use `parseInt`

```js
let num1 = "$45";
let num2 = "$70";


function getValue(num) {
  return parseInt(num.split('$')[1]);
}

let sum =  getValue(num1) + getValue(num2);

console.log("$" + sum);
```